# Why does Notepad++ display some Unicode characters as square?

Tags: notepad++, unicode, special-characters, utf-8

It can display `ₐ₊₋` but some other subscripts (like `₂ₙ`) are converted to squares. When I copy that square and paste on here the problem disappears: `₂`. Why is that? The file is encoded in UTF-8.

FYI: [Unicode subscripts and superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on whether the font you use has these symbols defined or not.

I found a basic way to change the font [here](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/167/no-way-to-change-editor-s-font):

> - Choose the menu option Settings - Style Configurator…
> - In the Style configurator dialog, choose the Global Styles language
> - Then, select the Default Style style
> - Finally, in the Font Style area, you can select your favourite font and/or its size, too

When I pick a font from the list, it is applied immediately, so it's easy to see which one supports characters you need. Of course if you use more than "Global Styles" / "Default Style" then you should modify the above solution accordingly.

Comment: It seems that on Windows, *Segoe UI Symbol* is the only font that includes that particular symbol: ₙ

Comment: @Berend how about Arial, Time News Roman?

Comment: No. At least on my system (Windows 8.1) these do not contain subscript n.

Answer (score 1):

Settings > Preferences > MISC. > Check "Use DirectWrite"

[image]