# Why does Notepad++ display some Unicode characters as `⎕` only if the mouse cursor is on that line?

Tags: notepad++, unicode

I've created a simple apl file with a function for evaluating a polynomial:

```
polyval ← {+/⍵×⌽⍺*(⍳≢⍵)-1}
```

(note the newline at the end)

When in Notepad++, if the cursor is currently at the end of the first line, many of the unicode chars render as boxes:

[image: Unicode APL chars rendering as boxes]

But when I place the cursor on the second line (empty), all of the characters render correctly:

[image: Unicode APL chars rendering correctly]

How can I get the characters to render correctly, regardless of which line the cursor is on?

Edit for future visibility: This occurs whenever the cursor is adjacent to a matched set of braces.

Comment: I can't reproduce this; what font are you using in np++?

Comment: This happens when the cursor is just before or after the braces. Ask Notepad++ developpers.

Comment: I'm using the default font that it decided to use on my system - Courier New

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Notepad++ display some Unicode characters as square?](https://superuser.com/questions/1268498/why-does-notepad-display-some-unicode-characters-as-square)

Comment: @Toto interesting observation, you're correct, it only occurs when the cursor is immediately before or after one of these chars: `{}()`

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I've tried switching to a font that I know has the required characters (provided with the APL distribution), and the issue still occurs.

Comment: I've opened an Issue on github for this: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/9805

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to enable `Direct Write` in the MISC. Preferences window.

[image: image of preferences window with correct option highlighted]

I filed a bug with the maintainers [over on Github](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/9805), and this was the solution they recommended.  Until there is another solution this will have to suffice.

Comment: Works for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug with Notepad++ having to do with the display of matched braces.

You will notice that the problem happens for these four characters:
`{`, `}`, `(`, `)`.
The bug has to do with the in-place display when writing the matched braces/parenthesis
in red.

I haven't found a way to disable this feature, only of changing its attributes
inside *Settings > Style Configurator… > Global Styles > Brace highlight*.
But in any case, disabling it would be less than useful.

You may signal the bug in the
[Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Comment: I've filed a bug at their github repository; assuming there is no other resolution on the issue, this is likely the correct answer